# Injecting a Stateless EJB into another Stateless and using PersistenceContext

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, java-ee-7, persistence.xml, ejb-3.2

With JEE 5 / EJB 3.0 life of Java developers became much more easier.  Later, influenced by Spring and CDI, similar approaches were also adopted in JEE.
Now, I hope I am doing it right, but just to be sure:
I have several Stateless EJBs, which all query and / or modify the database. An example is

```
@Stateless
public class AddressDBService {

    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager em;
```

Some of the Stateless EJB refer the other services like this:

```
@Stateless
public class AVeDBService  {

@PersistenceContext
protected EntityManager em;

@Inject
private HomeToDealDBService homeToDealDBService;

@Inject
private AddressDBService addressDBservice;
```

and in the Stateless EJBs I have public methods like the ones below:

```
   @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
   public void saveEntity(Home home) throws EntityExistsException {
     this.em.persist(home);
     addressDBservice.saveAddress(home.getMainAddress(), home);
   }
```

While I am almost certain this usage is correct and thread-safe (the above services are in turn injected into JSF Managed Beans).
Could somebody confirm that my usage is correct, thread-safe and conforms good practices?

My usage seems to be conform with the following questions:

[Is EntityManager really thread-safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24643863/is-entitymanager-really-thread-safe)

[Stateless EJB with more injected EJBs instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256441/stateless-ejb-with-more-injected-ejbs-instances)

Answer (score 1):

The "is correct?" question can't be answered without know the goal of the project.
It could works? Yes, you have posted java-ee code that could deploy, but is not enough.

I usually use BCE (Boundary Control Entity) pattern and Domain Driven pattern. 
In this pattern we use EJB for business logic services or endpoint (JAX-RS) and all other injections, that are the Control part, are CDI objects.

Entities (JPA) could use cascade to avoid to manually save related entities:

`addressDBservice.saveAddress(home.getMainAddress(), home);`

can be avoided if you define the entity like this:

```
@Entity
public class Home {
    @ManyToOne(cascade=ALL)
    private Address mainAddress;
}
```

The `@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)` annotation usually respond to a specific transactions behavior, is not required, so is correct only if is what you want to do.

Comment: By "is correct?" I  mean primary if EJB and CDI could work together in the way specified.

Comment: You only talk about "Stateless EJBs", my point is that it could be correct, but you can use simple CDI for Control services, but isn't the "right" way only a best-practice pattern